# why does websocket "open" event does not trigger?

Tags: javascript, sockets, oop

I have a custom object:

```
function Serverfunctionality(){
    this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    this.uploaded_image = null


    this.sign_up = function (){
        this.socket.addEventListener("open" , () => {
            console.log('works')
            
            this.send_data();
            
            
                
            })
    }
}
```

I then call this function like this(which works) :

```
<button id="signupbutton" onclick="new Serverfunctionality().sign_up()"   type="button">Sign up</button>
```

but if I wanted to lets say create an instance of the object and call it on the instance. For example:

```
var main = new Serverfunctionality();
```

calling `main.sign_up()` doesn't work.

**note:** the `Serverfunctionality` is housed in a different file , I link the html and javascript files by using the following script tag: `<script src="client.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Comment: where/how is `main` defined? This approach will only work if `main` is a global variable. That's one of several major downsides of using inline `onclick` attributes - much better to add event handlers in JS with `addEventListener`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond main is defined inside of the client.js file as a global variable. outside of the object.

Comment: seems like no matter what I do , I only can call this function when defining a new object instance in the same line.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Bergi I am not getting any error , but the events of the function doesn't trigger. I am beginning to believe that this has something to do with connecting to the socket , since when the instance of the object is defined the connection then is "opened" .

Comment: Yes, if you do the `var main = new Serverfunctionality();` beforehand, the connection might already be opened and you won't get another `open` event. You'll have to put an `if` statement checking `this.socket` and calling `send_data()` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open event listener wasn't triggering because the connection was already established in my instance of `Serverfunctionality` with the  `this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');` declaration inside of the object blueprint. The reason why it works here: `<button id="signupbutton" onclick="new Serverfunctionality().sign_up()"   type="button">Sign up</button>` is because we were establishing the connection while creating  instance of `Serverfunctionality`, therefore we were able to handle the "open" event.

Instead of trying to run the  code block in the event of "open". check to see if the connection is open and then run since the connection will be open before the button is able to be pressed.

**code:**

```
this.sign_up = function (){
    
    if (this.socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN ) {
        console.log('works')
        this.socket.send("works")
        this.send_data();
        }
        
            
        
}
```